# Prove that $|f^{(k)}(0)|/k! \leq M (e/k)^k$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Assume that f(z) is an entire function and $|f(z)| \leq Me^{|z|}$.  Here's what I have gotten so far.  I used the Cauchy estimate which is really simple math and I've gotten it down to something like $n!M/k!r^n$ but I'm unable to find a way to deal with the exponential term.  Can someone give me some help?  I think I'm supposed to use a circle line integral but I'm still unsure of how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

By Cauchy's integral formula applied to the circle $|z|=r$, we get
$$
\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!} = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=r} \frac{f(z)}{z^{k+1}}\,dz.
$$
Hence:
$$
\left|\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}\right| \le
 \frac{1}{2\pi} \cdot 2\pi r \cdot  \max_{|z|=r} \left|\frac{f(z)}{z^{k+1}}\right| \le \frac{Me^r}{r^k}.
$$
This holds for any choice of $r$. To get the version you want, pick $r=k$. In fact, this is the best choice of $r$. (In the sense that other choices give a worse bound.)